# Highlight function calls but not first in quoted list in emacs

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, emacs-faces

In emacs lisp mode, I want to highlight all function calls one color, and all quoted symbols another color. For example, in `(foo 1 2 'bar)`, foo should be highlighted color 1 and 'bar should be highlighted color 2.

I was able to do this with the code below, however, it is also highlighting the first symbol in a list when the list is quoted. For example, in `'(nil a b c)`, nil should **not** be highlighted as a function call, and all items in that list should be highlighted as quoted symbols (color 2).

```
(defface font-lock-func-face 
    '((nil (:foreground "#6fc2ef"))
      (t (:bold t :italic t)))
  "Font Lock mode face used for function calls."
  :group 'font-lock-highlighting-faces)

(defface font-lock-quoted-face 
    '((nil (:foreground "#e1a3ee"))
      (t (:bold t :italic t)))
  "Font Lock mode face used for function calls."
  :group 'font-lock-highlighting-faces)

(font-lock-add-keywords 
 'emacs-lisp-mode
 '(("(\\s-*\\(\\_<\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)\\_>"
    1 'font-lock-func-face)))

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'emacs-lisp-mode
 '(("'[-a-zA-Z_][-a-zA-Z0-9_]*\\>" 0 'font-lock-quoted-face)))
```

There's also an image of what I'm looking at here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGZe5.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of the answer: The package [lisp-extra-font-lock](https://github.com/Lindydancer/lisp-extra-font-lock) highlights, among else, quoted expressions.

It also highlights:

- variables in the parameter lists of functions and variables bound by `let`, `pcase` etc. It distinguish between normal local variables and global variables defined by a `defvar` by using different colors.
- Back-quoted expressions (and un-highlights all `,`- and `,@`-escaped subexpressions)

For example:
[image]

Second part of the answer:

If you use the `lisp-extra-font-lock` package, your rule for highlighting functions work as you posted it, if you add it as the *last* rule, after you have enabled the package. That way it will not overwrite any other highlight:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 
 'emacs-lisp-mode
 '(("(\\s-*\\(\\_<\\(?:\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\)\\_>"
    1 'font-lock-func-face))
 'append)    ;; <-- Add after all other rules
```